# getting error while closing sqlite db in ios

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite

I'm getting an error while updating record and then closing the database.
Issue not occurring while inserting and selection.

Here my methods for updating record and closing the database.

```
func updateNumber(_ number: String, withCountryCode countryCode: String, forId id:String)
{
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "update number_table Set number = ?, countryCode = ? Where id=?", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("error preparing update: \(errmsg)")
    }
    if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, number, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("failure binding number: \(errmsg)")
    }
    if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, countryCode, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("failure country code: \(errmsg)")
    }
    if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, id, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("failure binding id: \(errmsg)")
    }
    if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("failure updating record: \(errmsg)")
    }
    if sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("error finalizing prepared statement: \(errmsg)")
    }
    statement = nil
}
func closeDB()
{
    if sqlite3_close(db) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("error closing database")
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("failure closing database: \(errmsg)")
    }
    db = nil
}
```

and I'm getting following console output.

> error closing database 
>   failure closing database: unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups

I'm finalizing update statement, though I don't know how this error is occurring. 
Please help me to solve this. 
Thank in advance.

Comment: Some other function you didn't share is probably not finalizing a prepared statement.

Comment: I've finalized all prepared statement that I'm sure.
Also, this error is occurring when this update method is being called.

Answer (score 0):

you need to finalize your query statement after doing the tsql process...

```
var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
..
..
sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
```

Comment: Please take a look on my comment in question section